# where and how do I code an event handler for a rails 3.1 select tag onchange event?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I am trying to do a very basic onChange event handler for a Rails 3.1 select tag.  Most of the solutions I find are specific to ajax, but I am looking for something more simple, and what I have coded does not even seem to be recognized.  In my view, I have the following:

```
<h4><%= f.select :challenge_type, options_for_select(challenge_types, selected_type),
  :onchange => 'show_appropriate_challenge()' %></h4>
```

In my xxx.js.coffee file I have this (I tried many different alterations of this, none seem to make a difference):

```
$('show_appropriate_challenge') ->
   alert('Hello from your onChange handler')
```

When I select an option from the drop down, nothing happens, and there are no messages in the console.  Even if I change my select tag's onChange to something invalid (i.e. ...onchange => 'no_such_function()' ...), I still get no errors, so I suspect I am missing a configuration item or other item that hooks everything together.

What other items might I need to add, or what changes to either code snippet might be needed?

Thank you for any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Please, update your view to:

```
<h4><%= f.select :challenge_type, options_for_select(challenge_types, selected_type),
  :id => 'challenge_selector' %></h4>
```

This will add an `id` with the name `challenge_selector` to your `select` tag. Now, you can bind an on change event to this id, using coffeescript, like this:

```
$('#challenge_selector').on 'change', ->
   alert('Hello from your onChange handler')
```

Comment: Thank you - I made these changes, but still there is no alert when I select an item from the drop down.  Do I need to register the onchange handler or add something else?  I see no errors in the log files, and the console shows that it compiled application.js successfuly.  Should I see any changes to application.js?  I do not.